# Creating pandas dataframe column when a value in the row appears in a list in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three columns:
A column with values.
A column with a list, in which the value resides.
A column with a list, where each item in the list matches an item in the prior list.

I want to remove from the first list the value that appears in the first column, and then remove its associated value from the second list.  I want these to become their own separate columns.

See below for what it is currently like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | (12, 20, 25) | (100, 200, 300) |
| 34 | (34, 3, 4, 5) | (10, 15, 20, 900) |
| 56 | (101, 56, 7) | (98, 97, 96) |
| 78 | (78) | (13) |

And I want it to be like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 20, 25 | 200, 300 | 12 | 100 |
| 34 | 3, 4, 5 | 10, 15, 20, 900 | 34 | 10 |
| 56 | 101, 7 | 98, 96 | 56 | 97 |
| 78 |  |  | 78 | 13 |

I have tried iterating through each row and going through each list to find what matches column A and then moving that value to a separate column, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood your problem correctly, you need to find the index in the lists in cols B,C for each element in A.

This can be done in 2 steps:

##### 1) Cleaning step

this might not be relevant to you, both the dataframe columns B,C for me was a string of tuples instead of lists. This code just gets it into correct format:

```
from ast import literal_eval
def as_list(x):
    if type(x) is tuple:
        return list(x)
    elif type(x) is list:
        return x
    else:
        return [x]

df['B'] = df['B'].apply( literal_eval).apply(as_list)
df['C'] = df['C'].apply( literal_eval).apply(as_list)
```

##### 2) Code:

```
# get index in list B for element in A
df['index'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'].index(x['A']), axis=1) # you can do without saving this intermediate step, but I'm saving it for ease of calcs

# generate column D and E
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'][x['index']], axis=1 )
df['E'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C'][x['index']], axis=1 )

# update columns B and C
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'][:x['index']] + x['B'][x['index']+1:], axis=1)
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C'][:x['index']] + x['C'][x['index']+1:], axis=1)

# output
df.drop(columns=['index'])
```

Output :

```
    A          B              C   D    E
0  12   [20, 25]     [200, 300]  12  100
1  34  [3, 4, 5]  [15, 20, 900]  34   10
2  56   [101, 7]       [98, 96]  56   97
3  78         []             []  78   13
```